# django-filebrowser not accessible and a 404 is thrown

Tags: django, django-admin, django-filebrowser

> Page not found (404) Request Method:
>     GET Request URL:
>     http://beta.mysite.com/admin/filebrowser/
>
> The requested admin page does not
>   exist.

`django-filebrowser` requirements:

- django 1.0+ ( I have 1.1 )
- PIL ( I installed `python-imaging` )
- Grappelli ( I installed the latest svn trunk, confirmed it works )

For filebrowser I:

- checked out latest svn, put in python path
- copied over media files to static host
- added filebrowser to `settings.py`, confirmed its picking it up because it once threw an Exception that PIL wasnt installed before I installed it
- I added the exact url line to urls.py: `(r'^admin/filebrowser/', include('filebrowser.urls')),`

One thing to note, I **did not modify the filebrowser settings.py**.

My site admin works, grappelli is applied to the admin, I tried `http://site.com/admin/filebrowser/` with the trailing slash, my url has a trailing slash, heres the full urls.py:

```
    urlpatterns = patterns('',

        (r'^$', 'django.views.generic.simple.direct_to_template', {'template':'homepage.html'}),

        # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
        (r'^admin/filebrowser/', include('filebrowser.urls')),
        (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),


        # add this or you'll get some error:
        # Reverse for 'grp_bookmark_get' with arguments
        (r'^grappelli/', include('grappelli.urls')),

        (r'^search/$', 'site.search.views.search'),
        (r'', include('django.contrib.flatpages.urls')),

)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

apollo13 on freenode/#django solved this one.  I was supposed to go to `/admin/filebrowser/browse`.